# L298 high side driver: how does this actually work?

Tags: transistors, h-bridge, npn, l298

I recently took another look at the L298 since some students were having problems (due to the commonly discussed high V_CE-on of the combined high side and low side drivers). One thing that struck me as weird is that the L298 uses NPN transistors as both high side and low-side drivers.

How does the high-side driver actually switch when VB `<` VE `<` VC? For example, if Vs is 40V and Vss is only 5V, the base (as the diagram is drawn) is lower than both collector and emitter voltages, so I don't see how the high-side transistors are doing anything (other than maybe pulling the load up to ~4V and getting hot). Is there some base-drive logic that's not drawn in the diagram? I was thinking that it's possible the high side AND gates are actually open-collector, so that normally they would be pulled up to Vs through an internal resistor which is not drawn. That would sort of work - but in that case, the current gain is still limited by the inherent diode drop in the transistor, which also would change depending on the load current...

Is there a good analysis of the actual operation of the L298 h-bridge? It seems to be more complicated than it looks.

I've attached the diagram from the datasheet for convenience. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll probably find your answer in the [L293](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf) data sheet - it's the lower-power version of the 298 (without the heatsink). Here's what the 293 output stage looks like: -

[image]

The 293 (and I strongly suspect the same for the 298) has a PNP transistor that is much more conveniently driven from a low side logic signal.

I'm fairly sure the two devices work internally the same way - they have pretty-much exactly the same poor output specification. The diagram shown in the 298 spec "hints" at the limitations inherent in this type of H bridge because of the use of NPN transistors at the "top" and darlington transistors at the "bottom". See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m) for alternative devices using MOSFETs.

Comment: The PNP devices are typically pretty horrible, being of "lateral" construction, they have very low \$h_{FE}\$ so they can't realistically be used directly. Typical drops are 1.35/2.0V (source) and 1.2/1.7V (sink) for 1A/2A.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes a lot more sense that the "NPN transistors" in the L298 datasheet are actually not-really NPN transistors. I guess it's a Sziklai pair...or something similar.