# 12V motor running with 24V L293D H-bridge

Tags: voltage, motor

I have two 12V motors (300 RPM) running from a L293D H-bridge circuit. I find that the speed when I provide 12V is not satisfactory. Will it damage the 12V motors if I provide 18V or 24V? Will they go at higher RPM at higher voltage? The L293D circuit has maximum rating of 36V anyway.

Comment: Are you putting the motors in series now?

Comment: It really depends on what current you are running through the motors. See this, it should explain http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m I know it's for lower voltages but the same problem applies on 12 volt motors if you are taking a a few hundred milli amps - the chip will perform unsatisfactorily and burn usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The datasheet for your selected H-Bridge indicates a maximum amperage of 600mA per channel. It seems like this should be enough for your 12v motor. (whats the model number of the motor?)

So this could mean that your power supply is the problem. You are thinking about raising voltage:
[image]

But unless I misunderstand, what you need to do is this:
[image]

Unless of course one of your motors draws more than 600mA then you need a different H-Bridge

References:
battery images credit goes to http://www.zbattery.com/.
Texas Instruments datasheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf