# DC motor driving

Tags: dc-motor

I am using SRF-300CA-11440 DC motor in my application. ( 6V max )
([Datasheet for DC motor](http://www.sgstcl.com/up/1/engpdf/SRF300CAseries.pdf))

For motor driving purpose I am going to use L293D dc motor driver chip. L293D datasheet suggests "The L293D is designed to provide bidirectional drive currents of up to 600-mA at voltages from 4.5 V to 36 V"

So is there any problem while operating SRF-300CA-11440 DC motor on 5 Volts.

Can we use L293D for such low voltage motor driving.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question first and decide if the device is suitable: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m - it explains the problems associated with the L293 when driving low voltage motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the L293D can work at 5V but a 5V regulator should be added to avoid that the current pumped by the motor decrease the voltage below the the 4.5V where the "brain" of the L293 is not activated.

See page 6 of this document
http://content.solarbotics.com/products/documentation/kit10.pdf