# Using Adafruit Stepper controller to control 1A/phase stepper

Tags: current, driver, stepper-motor

I'm trying to control a stepper motor with [Adafruit Motor/Stepper/Servo Shield V1](https://www.adafruit.com/product/81), Arduino UNO and a 19V/5A power supply.
The motor uses 1A/phase making the driver overheat.

Is it possible to use the two stepper controls from the driver in parallel to control only one stepper and avoid overheating?

[image: Stepper motor]
[image: Adafruit V1]
<sub>(source: [prometec.net](http://www.prometec.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/sensorshield2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It uses an L293D driver. See this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m

Comment: You wouldn't think that paralleling bipolar devices was a good idea, however it actually was common in the era when these chips were a reasonable idea.  But as Andy points out **they are long obsolete now** with far, far, better choices on the market.  Also, if you are going to use a higher than rated voltage (which is indeed usual) you need a *chopping current regulator*, something the board you show does not seem to have.