# How to set up L293D - correct solution?

Tags: raspberry-pi, l293d

I want to control DC motors with L293D IC using my Raspberry Pi. I wanted to set it up similarily to this:

[image: Setup1]

But then I found one article on Instructabiles, which said that it would work, but correct solution was this:

[image: Setup2]

So my question is, why is the second circuit better? What do the capacitators do? I´m fairly new to electronics, so this may be a dumb question, but I really can´t figure it out.

Comment: Don't use the L293D, it is has terrible performance and is long obsolete.

Comment: So what would you recommend to use?

Comment: See this about the L293: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m