# DC motor humming troubleshoot

Tags: motor, dc, driver

We are working on a robotics project employing a differential drive.We are facing problems with one of the motors .While one of the motor runs fine, the other motor humms and sometimes doesn't run when connected through L298n driver,but works fine when directly connected to a battery.Tried checking the driver and everything is fine with it when tested with the other motor.How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance
Motor specs- DC motor with encoder
12V , 1A ,rated torque- 7kg-cm, stall torque - 17kg-cm

Comment: Any kind of motor control?

Comment: Yes, controlling it through arduino mega through pwm

Comment: So why do you think l298 is a problem?

Comment: What are the motor specs? How much current does it draw and what voltage does it drop when 'humming'? Does it still 'hum' when applying 100% PWM?

Comment: This may or may not apply depending on power rails and motor load current: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m

Comment: Gregory , I think l298n is fine.

Comment: Bruce! I have updated the motor specs.

Comment: Andy thanks for the link,didn't know abt the voltage drop!.But the other motor with the same specs works fine when controlled through the driver.

Comment: You probably have a open coil, check continuity from the driver through the motor and back.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem (where you have two *supposedly identical* "channels" and one is working but the other is *not* working) is easy to solve when you have the equipment in your hands. **Find the difference(s).** There must be difference(s) between the two channels, otherwise their behaviour really would be identical!

It is worth noting that difference(s) might be hidden due to a faulty assumption. For example, in your case, you are assuming that the motors have identical specifications and so are identical. In fact, one motor *might* be different than the other e.g. mislabelled, faulty manufacturing, damaged by previous use, etc. So always *check and list your assumptions*.

Two approaches to find differences which are quite suitable for beginners include:

1. Move devices/modules, *one at a time*, from the "failing" channel to the "working" channel and test whether:

   (a) the problem stays with the original "failing" channel (then the problem is *not* the component you moved to the other channel), or

   (b) the problem moves with the component to the other channel (then the problem *is* related to the component which you moved, although it *might* not be the component *itself*, but connectors, wiring etc. that were related to the move).

   One risk to this approach, is that by disturbing the electrical connections to move components between channels, you might change the problem, or it might disappear, without you knowing why (e.g. you might fix a high resistance connection when you move a wire).

   Or:
2. Make relevant measurements between the two channels, to find where the difference is. In your case, this would include measurements with DMM and 'scope to see if the *supposedly identical* PWM signals being sent to drive the two motors really are identical, If not, then you can use additional measurements to narrow down whether the cause is hardware or software (PWM generation).

   This approach has less risk of disturbing the cause of the problem than option 1 above (it is bad news if the problem "goes away" without you knowing why, because it could return in the future!) but it requires test equipment and ability to interpret the measurements.

Troubleshooting is not taught enough in many engineering courses. Learn fault-finding techniques at every opportunity and add them to your personal library for use later. Some good formal techniques are taught by [Kepner-Tregoe](http://www.kepner-tregoe.com/) and others. I have (over-)simplified their approach in my example above. Those simplified techniques would often not be appropriate in more complex cases.

An (unofficial) example of the Kepner-Tregoe "IS/IS NOT" approach is available here: http://www.itsmsolutions.com/newsletters/DITYvol6iss19.htm Although that is a software (IT) example, you can see how the *possible* causes are tested to see whether they match the problem description and other data.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
Some info sheet of driver L298n says it can have a voltage input of 5-35V, so I connect 6 1.5 AA batteries to it. It humps but does not move.
Later I connect 10 1.5 AA Battery to it, and it works