# What is the efficiency of a stepper motor driver?

Tags: driver, stepper-motor

We are using this stepper motor driver (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12779). In its datasheet, there is no mention of efficiency? How much is the efficiency in motor drivers like these?

Comment: This question is a little problematic - old drivers using things like power resistors had low efficiency, but modern *drivers* are quite efficient.  The overlooked problem is that stepper *motors* are generally quite inefficient.  So your question can be interpreted *literally* about efficiency of the *driver*, or the question you haven't quite asked but probably should have about efficiency of the *system* can be answered instead.  So far you have one of each type of response...

Comment: Does neither of the answers proposed, answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In motion control efficiency is usually mechanical output power (w*T) divided by electrical input power (U/I). Obviously it is different for different working points. For a standing stepper it's zero. On higher speeds sometimes nice figures may be reached, but bot very nice. Because for stepper you always take spares, otherwise it slips.

Answer (score 1):

A stepper motor driver is more or less a DC/DC converter with variable voltage output. So it's probably something around 90%. The same efficiency as a regular DC/DC converter.

Comment: It may actually be better than that, arguably the only loss in the *driver* is the FET RDSon.   However, efficiency of the *system* is going to be low, with most of the losses in the motor.

Comment: Hmmm, 90% is still kind of a good **approximation**, in order for a stepper to get any current, the current has to pass through 2 FETS, rather than 1 as a DC/DC would do. And then the current will rotate back into the stepper motor through the body diode of one of the FET's (or just a regular diode component), so there's some losses in the diode. And on top of this you got the switching losses, higher frequency => more losses in switching. If you want to get rid of the audible noise you need 20kHz+ => quite a bit of switching losses. 95+% maybe if you got some high quality top notch stuff.

Comment: The diode at least is a good point.

Comment: Guys, mechanical output of stepper sucks...

Comment: Good talk @GregoryKornblum

Comment: Best i can.....

Comment: We did our own experiment by measuring the input and output power of the motor driver and the efficiency came out to be around 75%.

Answer (score 1):

This is the stepper motor linked in the question: -

[image]

> How much is the efficiency in motor drivers like these?

It's not great. Consider the saturation voltage of the output transistors in the A3967 chip that drives the stepper: -

[image]

If you are taking the full 750 mA into your stepper then a total volt drop of about 3 volts can be expected. If you are running from a supply of (say) 15 volts, you are going to only see about 12 volts across the stepper motor coils. This means that peak input power is 15 x 0.75 amps = 11.25 watts whereas peak output power is only 9 watts. That means the peak efficiency is about 80%. If the supply voltage is (say) only 6 volts then nearly half that voltage is lost in the driver rendering an efficiency of only 50%.

There are better devices that only drop about 0.5 volts. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m) for a critique of other similar basic stepper drives / motor drives for a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote whoever it was (and I have my suspicions given that 4 downvotes in rapid succession have just happened to answers I have given and, this is very much reminiscent of last year when a certain person had a mini vendetta against me).

Comment: Thanks Andy for the answer. Did you actually mean a voltage drop of 2V instead of 3 since the output voltage is saturating at around 2V in the graph?

Comment: It's 3 volts given that there are two active elements in a H bridge: a source and a sink and the sink drops about a volt. Both elements are in series with the motor winding.