# How do I use a L297 IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor

I'm considering purchasing a L297 IC to drive my unipolar motor, but when I look at the datasheet [here](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/0/00/L297.pdf) , I can't make any sense of it. I've been working with an L293D, which makes a lot of sense because it has the logic supply, the enable pin, the power, outputs matched with inputs, etc. However, when I looked at the diagram, I couldn't figure out where to place the 4 coil wires and the common wires, and how to hook it all up to my Raspberry Pi. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't directly drive a motor with that chip. Does that help ease your pain?

Comment: I am pretty sure a 3-word query on google would resolve your problem.

Comment: If you look at the diagram on the front page of the datasheet you provided a link to you would see that it is not designed to drive the motor directly and needs a companion part such as the L298.

Comment: @Andyaka yes that's actually exactly what I was wondering thank you very much

Comment: @NeonCop Please write specific questions, a good specific question will generate good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm considering purchasing a L297 IC to drive my unipolar motor, but
>   when I look at the datasheet, I can't make any sense of it.

The first clue to what the L297 does is on page 1 of the data sheet: -

> The L297 can be used with monolithic bridge drives such as the L298N
>   or L293E, or with discrete transistors and darlingtons.

The second clue is the picture below: -

[image]

Notice how it interfaces to the motors via the fairly crappy L298.

If you are intent on using it may I draw your attention to [this Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m). It might contain useful information should you be thinking of using the L298 driver.