# How to control l298n voltage output

Tags: voltage, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

Recently I've been working on an RC car controlled by a Raspberry pi mounted on an RC car and connected to 2 motors via [l298n dual h-bridge](https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-vt19phz/product_images/uploaded_images/l298n-dual-2a-motor-driver-module-tronixlabs-australia-pinout.jpg?t=1416543556)
and im using a 12V battery to power the l298N However it only outputs between 2v-1v to the motors and that s not enough to move the car. 
So my question is how to controll the voltage output of This Driver ?

Comment: [This might be relevant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m)

Comment: they are talking about other drivers not the one i mentioned. 
but i can tell that voltage drop is a common problem as i see. 
and another thing i need to mention i think that the problem has a relation with the Pins Highlited in the image link i posted

Comment: No, the L298 is clearly and unambiguously covered. I wrote it so I should know this!

Comment: my bad i thought the L298N is diffrent then L298 (without N)
but that doesnt solve the problem does that mean there is no way to fix the voltage output ? it s a huge drop from 12V to 2V ...

Comment: Motor coils have a DCR value . WHat is it? You can measure with an ohm meter.  Yours better be >= 3 Ohms otherwise wrong bridge. What is voltage on both sides of motor coils

Comment: yess it s higher than 3ohms. i have a 12V battery input to the Driver and it ouputs aroud 2-1v.
in the morning i made some digging and i think the problem has to be with PWM signals if increase it maybe the output voltage will be higher ? i wanted to ask before tring because i dont study electronics it s just a hobby