# Whether I need to change the 5.0 voltage regulator?

Tags: microcontroller

I built a Arduino circuit that controls two stepper mottor. The power source I used is 9v, which is regulated to 5v to power Arduino and driver circuits.The Arduino is programmed to rotate the stepper motor.

The problem is Arduino gets powered, but the motor is not rotating. The regulator I am using is ams1117 5.0 dn728.I checked the ouput of the regulator , it produce stable 5v.But when it gets replaced by 7805 the motor rotates.

And the most strange thing is when I tried to measure the current from smd 5v regulator to IC , the motor runs and shows 80mA.

The power to atmega and to driver ICS are form sperate PCB which consist of 5.0 and 3.3 regulator.

From the  power board the atmega and driver circuit is powered.

Driver circuit

[image]

Arduino

[image]

Power circuit

[image]

Arduino circuit splited
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Why oh why are L293s so sh*t in low voltage applications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m)

Comment: Does L293 is problem here I am confused.I didn't get a clue to fix it.

Comment: What motor current are you expecting on full load or stall?

Comment: -1 because you couldn't even be bothered to properly trim the schematic images and at least try to present them at a readable scale.

Comment: I am sry I thought that it is readble if zoomed.sure I will edit them.  maximum load current is 400ma for two stepper motor.

Comment: @Ahmed then I suggest you take note about the linked Q&A.

Comment: What package size is the ams1117 5.0 ? SO-8, TO-252 or SOT-223?

Comment: @Andy aka   SOT - 223

Answer (score 2):

What package size is the ams1117 5.0 ? SO-8, TO-252 or SOT-223?

> @Andy aka SOT - 223

The thermal resistance (junction to ambient) for the AMS1117 5 volt regulator in a SOT-223 is 90°C/W. If you tried to take 400 mA from it you would dissipate 1.6 watts of power. The power calculation is 400 mA x (9 volts - 5 volts). This means that the temperature rise of the SOT-223 would be 144 °C and if you are at an ambient of (say) 30 °C, the temperature would reach 174 °C.

I expect that the device could reach this temperature in a second or so.

For a TO-220 μA7805 regulator, the equivalent thermal resistance is 19°C/W so 1.6 watts in an ambient of 30 °C would warm the device to about 60 °C and well within the maximum allowed internal temperature of 150 °C.

Given that the AMS1117 is rated for 125 °C I suspect this might be your problem (or at least be one of them).