# What PWM Frequency should be used for a 12V DC Gear motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, l298

I have [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-3-Smart-Car-Robot-Tire-Tyre-Wheel-1-48-70mA-DC-Gear-Motor-Remote/32522577093.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4d413DTP) 12V DC Gear motor, but I can't find much info about it online. The reason I have bought it was that I found this particular motor across several tutorials on how to build an RC car.

I will be using the L298N Dual H-Bridge Stepper Motor Driver to control four of these motors, and while I wait for it to arrive, I've started working on the software. After some research online, I have determined that the PWM frequency to be used varies depending on what motor/motor driver is being used.

That said, I would like to ask people who have used hardware similar to mine what PWM frequency should I use to use these motors optimally?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Good reasons to think carefully before you use the L298](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-low-voltage-power-supply)

Comment: Probably as low as you can live with to minimize switching losses.

Answer (score 1):

A frequency around 200-400Hz is fine. You have a larger range of duty cycle at low frequency.