# L293D (Motor Driver sheild. ) Overheating issue

Tags: l293d

I really do have a doubt. Actually I'm making Vplotter and for that I'm using 333nNm 0.31 A Stepper motor NEMA 17. And I'm giving an external supply of 5V and 1 A to motor driver sheild. Will L293D heat.

Comment: run it and find out

Comment: [Read this - L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on low voltage power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-low-voltage-power-supply)

Comment: I have *never* seen an application where L293. would have been the right choice as a motor driver. Literally never. Please follow Andy aka's link.