# L298N Current or Voltage source

Tags: driver

I want to power some coils using a controlled current, but I know as the coils heat the resistance changes. Will the L298N keep that current controlled at a certain enabler voltage?

Comment: Look up how chopping mode stepper drivers work; but then actually build it with as sense resistor, comparator, and an N-FET since you don't have a stepper motor but only a single coil that you presumably don't need to alternate the polarity of.

Comment: [L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on low voltage power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-low-voltage-power-supply).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:no.

By using current sensing and varying the pwm signal to the L298 you can achieve current regulation. This usually involves a microcontroller.

Comment: Ah ok, more steps then.

Answer (score 0):

How much current do you need to regulate?
Do you need to use a Full Bridge configuration to control your "coils"
What are your coils, heating, solenoid???
The L298 is a very old and inefficient device using BJT technology, it would be more efficient to use a MOSFET type device.
The L298 does not have onboard current control, you have to provide an external control device to read the current and control the input of the L298.
There are other devices that have onboard current limit control, you will have to do some research.
Look up the A4988 motor driver.

Comment: The A4988 is indeed the sort of drive topology in that it's a current mode chopper.  But I suspect it has a step/direction interface; since the OP isn't actually driving a stepper motor but just a random coil they need something they can command more explicitly.