# Powering up l298n module

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi, h-bridge

I have a l298n motor driver, hbridge, which i am using with my raspberry pi. I am supplying 6V to the hbridge from a battery holder that takes 4 AA cells so in total it is supplying 6V, yes. Now the problem begins when i attach 2 DC motors to the hbridge and when the code is run from my pi to start the motors... The motor runs for 1 second and then stops and the led indicator in the hbridge also goes off... Now i am here to ask what can cause this problem? I feel that i should supply more power to the l298n because i have read in some places it requires 12V and i am just giving in 6V. Is what i am thinking the actual problem or is the problem something else?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. Please attach a schematic to make this question more concrete.

Comment: I once tried L298N running toy motors (TT130 3V~6V) yellow toy motors) , using 6V (4 AA cells). Your batteries might be running out, so too weak to move the motors. So you might try using new batteries and/or use 3V toy motors.

Comment: You might the following tutorial useful: (1) Build a robot buggy using L298N - Rpi.org Projects:
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy

Comment: The minimum voltage must be VIH+2.5 = ~ 5V. So, 4 AA cells are not enough (for a long time ...). Also starting with low PWM for high inrush current...

Comment: Okay thanks a lot everyone. I think i will have to change my batteries with a new one or get some more of them am i correct? Your all answers were very to the point and have helped a whole lot. Thanks again!

Comment: [Problems with L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on a low voltage supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-low-voltage-power-supply)