# Choose battery for ultrasound transmitter circuit (voltage and current rating)

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-operated, ultrasound

I would like to build this circuit which is an ultrasonic speaker (from this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/AJ6hLpapgL4), skip to time 3:53 for the schematic, and also see the [designer's website](https://www.roboticskanti.com/post/high-frequency-sound-generator)) but I don't know what voltage and current rating I have to choose for the battery.

The regulator is a [L78S05CV](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/889461.pdf), the 555 is a NE555P. The transducers are similar to those found in proximity sensors, I would like to connect 6 in parallel.

The transducers get driven by a [L293D](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf).

What's the operating voltage and current needed by this circuit? I need to choose an appropriate battery for it.

[image: schematic]

Comment: The schematic Will Not Work! The sander (sender?) and receiver transducers are all paralleled and have one terminal connected to L293 output 3 and the other transducer terminal connected to L293 output 4. Then inputs 3 and 4 are paralleled producing no signal to the transducers. One of the L293 inputs must be inverted for the L293 to "boost" the voltage (like a bridged amplifier) as wrongly said in the video. The voltage of the 3.7V battery shown is too low for the circuit.

Comment: (Oops. @Audioguru: excellent catch. I should read diagrams more carefully instead of stating falsehoods about paralleling. Or wasting time refreshing memories about the impossibility of having 555 output and discharge inverted/complementary with respect to each other. And the annoyance of none instead of half the L293(D)/L298 drivers inverting.) (I don't think any of the transducers are intended as receivers/sensors.)

Comment: @Audioguru thanks for the answer anyway the speakers are all transmitters precisely because it's a speaker unfortunately the translation doesn't help so could you tell me how should I change? explaining more simply because I'm not an expert like you

Comment: @greybeard hello friend I checked your answers and those of Audioguru but I think maybe you misunderstood you because the transducers are all transmitters, and connected in parallel, all 6 transducers then I connect them to output pins 3 and 4 of the l293d, and in input 3 and 4 connect output of 555 maybe the only problem could be the bindings with enabled dell l293d, since enabled 1 and 2 i don't think it has to be linked to anything

Comment: The problem is that all outputs of inputs driven in parallel should be at the same potential, interconnected or not. To get *some* effect, connect the other terminal of the transmitter(s) to GND.

Comment: @greybeard I'm sorry but on many tutorials on the web when the motors are connected to the l293 the positive connect it to output 3 and the negative to output 4 and furthermore each output corresponds to the relative input. so I don't understand why I have to connect the negative of the transducers directly to the battery gnd, tell me exactly what I have to do to make them work because at this point I'm not understanding anything anymore

Comment: Please provide a hyperlink to *one* of those many tutorials showing how the inputs are driven. Are they connected to each other?!

Comment: @greybeard then all the tutorials of the l293d concern the control of DC motors and not transducers and I believe that the situation is different I believe that enable is the pwm that is the output of the 555, I don't connect anything to the inputs, instead the outputs 3, 4 li I connect to the positive and negative of the transducers, what do you think?

Comment: @greybeard now I'm sending you the link of another guy who uses the l298n which is the same as the l293d and he didn't connect anything to the inputs and the pwm only connected it to enable and the positive and negative terminals of the transducers he connected them to the outputs or as you say you connect the positive of the piezo to output 3 and the negative of the piezo to gnd, you tell me here is the link: https://youtu.be/TQOabMOMGoE

Comment: The schematic shows both enables connected to VSS, not any PWM or the NE555. That hyperlink is to another 6 minute video - shall I sit through it not knowing what to look for? link to the second, or at least identify it!

Comment: (Example for the "original" video: `https://youtu.be/AJ6hLpapgL4?Autoplay=0&t=233` [Robotics Kanti's schematic](https://youtu.be/AJ6hLpapgL4?Autoplay=0&t=233) - just append `?t=###`with ### the time into the video in seconds - or in minutes&seconds: `t=3m53s`)

Comment: @greybeard so now i'm not able to insert the video link anyway, i'll describe it to you, this other guy not robotics kanti, but another one, i connected differently, he connected the output of the ne555 with enable 3,4, then to inputs 3 ,4 of the l293d didn't connect anything, then connected the positive and negative terminals of the piezos, to the 3,4 outputs of the l293d, so now i ask you this is the right way to connect everything?

Comment: @greybeard unfortunately the translation doesn't help me understand (I'm Italian) and all the l293d tutorials are about DC motor control and not piezos, that's why you can get confused, I hope to finish soon this is the last part

Answer (score 3):

The L78S05CV needs at least 8V to operate. This means that your battery pack has to provide this voltage under all operating conditions. The circuit should also be able to operate with up to 30V.

A protected(!) 3S lithium-ion battery pack could do this. Please don't just use bare cells or a RC battery pack, though, since these don't have protection circuitry. You will also need an appropriate charger.

Alternatively, you can use a 12V lead-acid battery. These are much cheaper and easier to operate.

The operating current will be at most 1A since the L293D can't handle more, and in reality, it'll likely be much less. Any reasonable lithium-ion or lead-acid battery can handle this.

You might also want to add bypass capacitors to ground at the input and output of the 7805 (i.e. 100µF electrolytic + 1µF ceramic at the input, and 100nF ceramic at the output)

Comment: ok so 9 volts and 500 mah are fine? how far can i go? how can I increase the sound of the transducers by acting on the volts or amperes, then I knew that the capacitors near the 780 were inserted only if the power supply was alternating current but here it is continuous

Comment: Sure, a 9V 500mAh battery (primary cell) should work fine, but it won't last very long. You'll have to monitor the current draw if you want to increase the voltage (and therefore the sound level). It shouldn't go higher than 1A, else you risk burning out the driver L293D. The capacitors are needed to provide bursts of power to the circuit, which the battery alone can't.

Comment: thanks jonathan so to increase the volume I have to increase the voltage without ever exceeding 1A of current, right? so can I insert a 12V 500mAh to have a greater volume or also the current must increase without exceeding 1A? I'm not an expert explain to me simpler

Comment: You can increase the voltage until one of the following things happens: 1. You reach 30V; 2. The current draw exceeds 1A (though ideally you'd stay below 0.5A); 3. Any of the chips get too hot. Higher voltage means it'll be louder.

Comment: ok one last piece of information you mentioned the insertion of the capacitors downstream of the 7805 I remembered that they would be inserted if there had been an alternating power supply, mine is continuous is that all right? and then the first was inserted between positive and gnd and the second between gnd and output but you put 3 in it, could you tell me what values? and then for the battery I can increase the volts up to 30, but with the current I must always be under 1 A better if under 500 mAh, right?

Comment: "mA" and "mAh" is not the same. "mAh" is the capacity of your battery, "mA" is the current drawn from it. The current should be below 500mA. The capacitors I recommended you to install aren't for filtering rectified AC, they're there to improve the regulator's transient response and ensure its stability. You still need them even with a battery. The values are already in the answer. To repeat them once more: 100µF electrolytic + 1µF ceramic in parallel at the input of the 7805, 100nF ceramic at the output of the 7805.

Comment: okok okay the problem is the translation that doesn't make me understand anything so I connect the capacitors at the input to each other in parallel and then after I connect them in parallel between the input and gnd and then the third capacitor I connect it between the output of the regulator and vcc of the 555 or between the gnd of the regulator and the output of the regulator? I believe the second. then one more thing in my question in the comments below before your answer Audioguru and greybeard users said something about the l293d of the output pins but i don't see error what Think you?

Comment: The circuit needs to be fixed for it to produce even a low level of ultrasonics. The input and output of L293 #3 is exactly the same as the input and output of the L293 #4 then the transducers get NO SIGNAL! One terminal of each transducer either needs an inverted signal like on a bridged amplifier or it must be grounded. The transducers should have a datasheet listing their maximum allowed AC voltage which is probably much higher than 5V p-p.

Comment: @Audioguru thank you very much for your answer unfortunately I still don't understand what I have to change tell me in a simple way how can I do it because the translation doesn't help me I have to add a bridge amplifier or do I just have to change the connections, and if I have to change them how should I do it

Comment: Since this circuit does not work, I found another similar circuit on You Tube (DIY Ultrasonic Audio Laser) that uses a TC4428A driver that has two differential outputs that can drive the paralleled piezo 40kHz transducers.  The 555 and this TC4428A do not need a 7805 voltage regulator. All electronic circuits need a power supply bypass capacitor. I am not at All About Circuits forum anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 9 V "transistor" battery. It has sufficient voltage for the regulator's voltage drop and it can definitely supply the current drawn by your simple circuit.

Comment: I wish people will stop posting fake and defective circuits on You Tube and I wish You Tube will stop paying them. I agree that IF the circuit is fixed then its power supply current will be very low since an ultrasonic transducer is a low current piezo. The squeaky sounds in the video might have been recorded from a other circuit that produced the squeaks. Commercial products that work produce REAL SOUNDS that seem to come from where the ultrasonic array is pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of a "weak" battery such as a 9 V "transistor" battery is its limited current capability. (Just don't let it get too hot.)

As [Audioguru commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/647681/274544?noredirect=1#comment1719165_647681), INPUT3&INPUT4 are driven by the same signal in the schematic in the question. As both drivers are enabled, OUTPUT3&OUTPUT4 should be at the same potential all the time:
Connecting transducers "between" both these outputs should not lead to any current flow.

Instead, connect the other terminal of the transducers to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2CZCz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While datasheets disagree generously on quiescent current, the L29X driver's is notoriously high:
An awful choice for battery power.

Comment: [Outlandish idea about full bridge using L293](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/647976/274544) all on its own.

Comment: See also: [L293/L298 at low supply voltages](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108690).

Comment: (Some datasheets recommend \$V_{logic}\$ no higher than 7 Volts, others allow up to \$V_{bridges}\$ . I hate when that happens.)

Comment: so if I understood correctly this circuit should work, so I make the pwm signal enter input 3 and I connect all the piezos positively to output 4 and negatively to gnd, but then vlogic needs a voltage of 5 volts so I can directly connect them from 555 without adding the capacitor? and then I really have to put all the inputs and the enable to gnd and ancue vbridge, I never have to insert the power supply for the piezos, it seems strange to me

Comment: no sorry I saw better vbridge is connected to the 9 volt power supply so could you explain to me how you connected vlogic and why you put the enable and inputs to gnd, when usually the pwm signal is connected to enable and not to input?

Comment: `input 3 [and] output 4` No. Use one half bridge's input&output, I chose 4 for proximity. start with *one* transmitter. `\$V_{logic}\$ needs a voltage of 5 volts` Annoyingly, datasheets don't agree among manufacturers: Please provide the exact type of your specimen, link to manufacturer's contemporary (to the IC) datasheet welcome. `[can I leave out physically close decoupling capacitors]?` Don't expect reliable operation without. `[do] I really have to put all the inputs [including] enable to [defined levels]?` Doing so is good design practice. Disabling the unused half lowers supply current.

Comment: `explain to me how you connected Vlogic` ? There is a buffered battery right there. `usually the PWM signal is connected to enable` Don't give me *usually*, but a link to *one* schematic/documented circuit to discuss. (Which is *not* the purpose of comments on StackExchange, at that).

Comment: ok graybeard I think I understood everything, you're a really good person the "ancue" meant "also" I said it because it seemed strange to me to also connect the enable to gnd, since it is the enable pins that receive the PWM signal. one last question if I don't find the capacitors ceramic, what is the polarity that I have to respect? Could you write the "+" symbol for the capacitors?

Comment: If resorting to polarised capacitors, connect "-" to GND.

Comment: okok my friend i understand in case i have problems i will answer you on this diacussion

Comment: The video wrongly says that the L293 "boosts" the voltage to the transducers, which would happen if the L293 drivers are driven differentially (one input inverted) like in a modern bridged amplifier.

Comment: @greybeard so if I want to connect all 6 piezos, I do this: I take three piezos I connect them in parallel, and then as you did greybeard, one terminal of the piezos goes to output 3 and the other to GND, and the PWM to input 3 , then I take the other 3 piezos I connect them in parallel, and this time I connect one terminal to output 4 and the other to GND and then the pwm takes it from input 4, in a nutshell it's like I separate them, right??

Comment: @greybeard or another possibility is to connect all 6 piezos in parallel, and then connect the positive terminal to output 3 and the negative terminal to output 4, to input 3 and 4 I connect them to GND, and I let the PWM enter to enable 3,4 and instead enable 1,2 I connect it to GND like all inputs, right?

Comment: (Connecting both inputs to GND, what output do you expect?) The comment before looks right. If it does not work, use about 1 Hz and LEDs with series resistor as loads: at the NE555 output as well as at the L293(D)'s. If it works, compare to connecting one "triplet" of transducers to \$V_{supply}\$ instead of GND - you may need to invert it. (Are you aware of transducer polarity?)

Comment: @greybeard I want them to connect all 6 piezos but I have to figure out how to do it. so in my previous two comments, the first one is the most feasible, which consists of the two piezo triplets, right? but I still don't understand, how should I invert the piezos as you said in the end, could you make me a little drawing so I can see how to connect them inverted?

Comment: Without the question identifying/showing the transducers, how can anyone provide a drawing? Same as with loudspeakers: Say you have two identical drivers. Drive one with a pulse: The moving part starts in one direction. Put the other driver in parallel, apply a pulse again: Either they start in the same direction, or in opposite, cancelling out much of any acoustic effect. Once each triplet is connected successfully to an output and to ground with all six moving in the same direction, try connecting what was at GND (of *one* triplet) to \$V_{bridges}\$ .

Comment: @greybeard ah ok then it was as I said, I said right in the comment before I'll explain everything, take three piezos and connect them in parallel, I connect the positive terminal to output 3, instead I connect the negative terminal to GND as you did and the pwm I connect it to input 3, and for the other three piezos I connect them to ouput 4 and so on. The enable pins connect them all to GND. In fact, I asked you how to connect all 6 of them, so to solve it I divide 3 of them on one side by half a bridge and the other three on the other and I connect them in parallel

Comment: @greybeard okok that was just what I wanted to know, and that is how to connect them 3 piezos in a half bridge, and then you told me that I have to connect them in parallel, ok thanks I am following your circuit that you sent me, however I believe that output 3 can drive three piezos in parallel, with the positive terminal of the three piezos in parallel connected to output 3 and the negative terminal of the piezos in parallel connected to GND

Comment: `The enable pins connect them all to GND` No. ENABLE A for the unused half (half-bridges 1&2) to GND so as not to inflate supply current. ENABLE B needs to be between 2.3 V and 7 V for half-bridges 3&4 to work (oops - fumble in my schematic. Use a voltage divider or the 5 V from a 78X05 if using such).

Comment: @greybeard ah ok okay I'll do it like this then, thanks for everything my friend a hug

Comment: Get rid of the old L293 IC. Use a modern TC4428A driver IC which has TWO Differential Outputs that feed Double the supply voltage signals to the transducers so that they are loud enough. If one wire of each transducer is grounded then the transducers get only half the voltage that a differential connection provides. Use 12V to power the new circuit.

Comment: (@Audioguru: neglected to explicitly address  Il D?)

Comment: DO NOT connect one wire of each transducer to ground. Instead drive the transducers from differential outputs of a TC4428A driver that effectively doubles the signal voltage swing to the transducers. I am continuing this discussion with more details and more schematics at All About Circuits.

Comment: All About Circuits wrongly banned be for about an hour. They did not say why. I am back there where this discussion continues with more details.