# How to calculate the DeadBand time for H-bridge in Cycles

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, arm, h-bridge, texas-instruments

I am using L298n H-bridge driver and using Texas Instruments tiva c tm4c123gh6pm microcontroller. According to the datasheet (I am using source rise and fall delay because according to my understanding these delays are from microcontroller)

[image]

[image]

I am using deadband generator in tm4c123gh6pm and the register contains the description that enter the value in cycles. As you can see in the figure below its an 11-bit register and the maximum value i can enter in it is around 2^11 = 2k so i used chatgpt version 3 and it was not giving me a proper answer.

[image]

This last picture is the picture of my calculation for clock that i am using and the desired frequency  for the PWM. I would be thankful if someone could help me out in this matter.

[image]

Comment: Advice: [Problems with L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on a low voltage supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/problems-with-l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-a-low-voltage-supply)

Comment: @Andy aka I checked the answer and they are discussing which one to use and the load these drivers can drive. I want to know how to calculate the deadtime in cycles from the above details.